# Spring Data for Couchbase - Metadata Information

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, couchbase, spring-data-couchbase, couchbase-java-api

I am new using Spring Data for Couchbase, I defined this object

```
public class Building {

    @NotNull
    @Id
    private String id;

    @NotNull
    @Field
    private String name;

    @NotNull
    @Field
    private String companyId;
}
```

but I am not sure if the id defined in the object will be the same of the Couchbase Metadata Information and how to define the format of it

```
.cas
.expiration
.flags
.id
.type
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to worry about the meta attributes, they are automatically created by couchbase. Just the @Id is mandatory.